# Python method's arguments validation, ArgError

Tags: python, validation, arguments

When programming in `C#` I usually write following arguments validation code:

```
void Process(object item) {
    if (item == null) throw ArgumentNullException();
    // code
}
```

Is it 'Pythonic' to do similar validation in `Python`? I really don't want anybody pass `None` to `Process` method. What type of `Python Exception` should I use? (There are no standard `ArgError` or something like this)

```
def Process(item):
  if item == None: raise ArgNoneError('item')
  # code
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, you'd just try to make do with the arguments you got -- if someone passes `None` to your function it will fail anyway.  There is no need to add complexity to your code without any benefit.  Quite the contrary -- often such tests prevent your code from working for cases it would work fine wwithout the tests.

If you want to raise some error anyway, use `TypeError` -- it is meant for this purpose.

Comment: I've shown slightly incorrect example there. Actually I have `initialize` method, which only saves passed arguments into class attributes, so it does not fail if someone passes `None` (but call to other methods will fail), thats why I want to add some validation.

Comment: @Roman: That actually doesn't really matter.  Clearly document what types you expect.  If someone passes something else, they'll be on there own.

Comment: It's absolutely incorrect solution from code-smells coders. You must validate all arguments you want to use and return useful for user exceptions, not like "Program is down, object can't be null". There must be "The customer can't be null in ClassName.MethodName()"

Comment: @Artem: What you describe is the usual Java approach.  In Python, most people take the more light-weight duck typing approach I outlined.  It's a double-edged sword, agreed, but it's definitely not "incorrect".  (The error message you get is usually quite to the point, and not "program is down", btw.)

Comment: I'd argue that it depends on what your function is dealing with.  If the function receives values from an end user (who may or may not know what they are doing and/or how to code), it should carefully check that the input is reasonable, and output a usable error message.  If, however, the code will just be used by coders, let them figure out why there crappy coding broke your set-up.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`TypeError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError):

> *exception* **TypeError**
>
> Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. The associated value is a string giving details about the type mismatch.